# Can DisplayMode set resolution to Screen Resolution?

Tags: java, displaymode

So I am using the DisplayMode to set my resolution for a fullscreen as follows

```
DisplayMode dm = new DisplayMode(1440,900,64, DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);
```

My question is,  Is there anything that I can put in place of 1440, 900 to get the app to set the resolution to whatever the computer it is running on is currently at?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`Toolkit#getScreenResolution`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getScreenResolution()) and [`Toolkit#getScreenSize`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getScreenSize()) for starters

You can also use (something similar to)

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();

Rectangle bounds = gd.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
```

to get the screen bounds of given `GraphicsDevice`/screen (the example gets the default screen device)

Take a look at [`GraphicsEnvironment`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html) and [`GraphicsDevice`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html) for more details